# Default implementation of protocol implementing protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollviewdelegate, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

I'm trying to create a protocol that would be implemented by certain classes, all of them should also implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`. What I thought of is for my new protocol to implement the protocol `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

```
protocol MyProtocol: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var myVar: NSString { get }
    func myMethod()
}
```

As the protocol should have its default implementation I also created an extension for this protocol.

```
extension MyProtocol {
    func myMethod() {
        print("I'm printing")
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("I'm scrollin")
    }
}
```

It compiles, but does not work. What am I doing wrong and what would be the right way to create a default implementation of expanded protocol?

Comment: I think you are on the right track. My guess is that you have to override the setter for the delegate in your protocol and call super.delegate = theDelegate

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work".  What happens?  That's not an acceptable description of the problem.

Comment: At the first glance you are on the right track, but as of Swift 2.2, delegate methods defined in protocol extensions are not "found" from Objective-C code. You need to extend the class that conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`, that is define an extension method `scrollViewDidScroll` in a concrete class `MyScrollViewDelegate` or `MyScrollViewViewController`.

Comment: @nhgrif it means the function is not entered

Answer (score 5):

What you want to do is the following:

```
protocol MyProtocol{
    var myVar: NSString { get }
    func myMethod()
}

protocol MyProtocol2{
    var myVar2: NSString { get }
    func myMethod2()
}

extension MyProtocol where Self: MyProtocol2 {
    func myMethod() {
        print("I'm printing ")
    }
}

class anotherClass: MyProtocol, MyProtocol2 {
    var myVar: NSString {
        return "Yo"
    }

    var myVar2: NSString {
        return "Yo2"
    }

    func myMethod2() {
        print("I'm printing in myMethod2")
    }
}
```

In the above code MyProtocol2 is equivalent to your UIScrollViewDelegate,

hence what you will do is:

```
protocol MyProtocol{
    var myVar: NSString { get }
    func myMethod()
}

extension MyProtocol where Self: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func myMethod() {
        print("I'm printing")
    }
}

class anotherClass: NSObject, MyProtocol, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var myVar: NSString {
        return "Yo"
    }
}
```

Notice that another class subclasses NSObject, this is because if you do not do so, you will get the error

> `anotherClass` does not conform to protocol `NSObjectProtocol`

This error is because `UIScrollViewDelegate` itself is defined to be extending `NSObjectProtocol` which is an objective-C protocol implemented by NSObject.

So make your class inherit from NSObject to conform to the NSObjectProtocol. Vanilla Swift classes do not.

Comment: I want to move this functions implementation out of class' body, as it is supposed to act the same way in each class that implements the protocol. I know it is not what protocols are meant for, but I want to create a protocol extension with implementation of method from the other protocol (which is implemented by the primary one).

Comment: yes you can still implement the methods of UIScrollViewDelegate in the protocol extension

Comment: Thanks for the answer @uchiha
I tried doing this for where `anotherClass` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, which is already a descendant of `NSObject`, but the `scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` function in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` is not correctly overridden. It seems like I only added another version of `scrollViewDidScroll` to my class.

I understand that with the method you described, you'll be able to satisfy one protocol with functions from another protocol, but would you ever be able to create a default implementation for the `scrollViewDidScroll` function?